# How to select rows in a list of data frames by column values

Tags: r

I have a list (lfs01)with four data frames, each data frame has a different number of columns and rows.

I would like to filter the rows in all data frames by values in one column (if == 1). The variable is called "a" in the first two data frames and "A" in the last two.

I looked at previous similar questions but unfortunately I did not find the solution.

Here are things I have tried:

````
data<-lapply(lfs01, function(x) filter(x ,'a'==1))

data<-lapply(lfs01, function(x) filter(x ,'a'==1|'A' ==1))

``` 

# Result:  a - list of 4 data frames with 0 rows.

 ```
data<-as.list(1:4)
for(i in 1:length(lfs01)){
  data[[i]]<-lfs01[[i]]%>%
    filter('a'== 1)
}
```
# and

```
data<-map(lfs01, ~filter(.x, 'a'%in%1 ))

```

# Results as above - list of 4 data frames with 0 rows. 

Many thanks in advance!
````

Comment: what is wrong with the code you have tried?  use `map2` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the column names to either lower or upper case and use the same `filter`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map(lfs01, ~ .x %>%
                rename_all(tolower) %>%
                filter(a == 1)
   )
```

---

In the OP's post, the column names are quoted inside `filter` which wouldn't work.  So, it can be

```
map(lfs01, ~ .x %>% 
                  filter(a == 1))
```

Comment: Changing the variable name did the trick. Now the loop (with the variable name outside ' ') and the 'map' , as corrected by Akrun, work.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach could be to rename the columns so that all the dataframes have the same name and it is easy to subset them. Another approach could be to subset the dataframes based on position if you know the position of that column beforehand.

If none of the above is possible then we can check if a particular name exists and use the `subset` command accordingly.

```
lapply(lfs01,function(x) if('a' == names(x)) subset(x,a == 1) else subset(x,A == 1))
```